# How to check FTP availability in batch file to stop running script

Tags: bash, scripting, ftp

I need to create a validation function in batch file to check for availability of FTP server because I'm executing `put` command then deleting my locally stored files. The Problem is if i don't check if FTP server is up, files are not `put` to server but locally deleted.

Comment: http://whatHaveYouTried.com . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What about simply use "ping"  and than use some condition with "$?" > when $? returns "2" (I think) the ftp server is down